# Topological space with certain properties

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

For each integer $n$, does there exist a finite, connected $n$-dimensional CW complex $X$, that is not homotopy equivalent to an $(n-1)$-(or smaller)dimensional CW complex so that $H_0(X, \mathbb{Z}) = 1$, and $H_i(X, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ for $i> 0$?

This is clearly true for $n = 0,1$. I realized that I can't prove existence (or lack of) in higher dimensions.

Comment: What is your example for $n=1$? I believe a connected graph with $H_1=0$ must be a tree and hence homotopy equivalent to a point.


Answer (score 5):

See Theorem 1.4 [here](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matberic/jonhAJB03306.pdf): For every $n>1$ there exists an acyclic group $G_n$ with finite $n$-dimensional $X_n=K(G_n,1)$ so that cohomological dimension $cd(G_n)$ of $G_n$ equals $n$. Now, take the complex $X_n$ as an example for your question. If $X_n$ were homotopy-equivalent to a complex of dimension $n-1$, then $cd(G_n)$ would be less than $n$, which is a contradiction.